# Why wget prints many new lines of status when downloading (using PuTTY)?

Tags: remote, wget, byobu, putty

Why wget prints many new lines, when connecting to an Ubuntu machine via a remote terminal session like PuTTY?

The issue is not just in wget but in byobu as well. Both programs behave queer.
I assume the trouble is somewhere in config of the system.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The program you are using for connecting probably doesn't understand some keycodes.

Comment: This looks like windows to me?

Comment: @Tim It's a remote session with a Windows client; the server appears to be Ubuntu. The problem might lie with PuTTY (or whatever PuTTY-like client is being used, but the interface and application icon look like PuTTY to me), but I recall there are environment variables (`TERM`, perhaps) that can be changed in the Ubuntu session to fix many such problems, so I'd be somewhat reluctant to close this until we know a fix in the Ubuntu system is impractical or otherwise unreasonable.

Comment: After your comment I tested my issue directly on the pc and all looks fine. So the trouble is somewhere around Putty. I'm using the same environment (windows, putty) to work with a few another linux servers but issue appeared just in the last case with Ubuntu 14 so I decided the trouble is in the new OS. Thanks for help.

Comment: When connecting with PuTTY, try `export TERM=vt100; tset` before issuing the command. Seems like PuTTY terminal misinterpret the codes to overwrite the last line. You can even try `TERM=dumb` (can't check now, no Windows installation arounde here :-))